# CoreData equivalent of SQL "Select column AS "AnotherColumnName from dbTable"

Tags: ios, sql, core-data

I have inherited an application that we are integrating to a new web services API, but the data model of the old app and the new back end do not match when it comes to DB column names, is there a CoreData equivalent to the SQL statement:

```
Select name AS 'AnotherName' from dbTable
```

That way I could easily map the app data model to the new APP backend.

Comment: This is not possible lie this. You might want to use a Core Data Entities `User Info` or `Versioning` (recommended) feature.

Comment: Look into `NSExpression`

Comment: @TomHarrington maybe you could elaborate a little on how to use that to change the name of a column ?